# Self-Saucing Pudding—Storing?

Tags: storage-method, cake, custard

I've made [this recipe](http://www.penandspoon.com/rhubarb-self-saucing-pudding/) once before and it turned out really well. I'd like to make it ahead of time for an event that I'm going to but I'm really not sure how it should be stored overnight.

The top of this dessert ends up with about an inch and a half of cake with a golden-brown crust. Beneath that it forms a custard-like rhubarb sauce that is fairly "liquidy" when it comes out of the oven but firms up as it cools.

I'll make it in the evening and will serve it early the next day. Should it be left on the counter or refrigerated? Covered or uncovered? Or, given the proximity of cake and custard to one another, is this a dish best left to serving immediately? Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I just asked the author. I'll let you know if she answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your answer, directly from the creator of the recipe:

> This dish is terrific if left for an hour or so after cooking as it
>   gives the saucy bit and the cakey bit some time to separate a little.
>   I have devoured leftovers of this 24 hours later, after i left them in
>   the fridge. In all honesty after being left for this time it's very
>   different to what it's like warm - more like a gooey pudding than cake
>   and a sauce, but absolutely delicious. I doubt very much that it would
>   reheat as it would dry out (although you could try it briefly in the
>   microwave if you have one).
>
> I hope that helps.
>
> By the way, the Guardian printed a version of this recipe which had
>   one of the ingredients (milk) missing from the method. Hopefully the
>   one you're using is the correct one, but if you do find the milk is
>   missing, the correct version is on my website
>
> Best wishes
>
> Sue

(just to make sure: I'm not Sue, this a copy of the email she sent me in response to the forwarding of your original question)

Comment: +1 because emailing the original author almost seems too obvious and I'm ashamed not to have even considered it.

Comment: @ logophobe It's very nice of her to answer so quickly too.